# How to set gstreamer v4l2src stream-mmap

Tags: gstreamer

I now try to use gst-launch to play the camera data, but when I use the following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 !video/x-raw, format=NV16, width=768, height=288, framerate=50/1 ! waylandsink
```

A buffer full warning occurs and frames are dropped:

```
rkcif_dvp: not active buffer, skip current frame, dvp stream[0]
```

I want to know whether there is `--stream-mmap=3` similar to v4l2-ctl in gst, which can be used to specify the number of mmap buffers. While I use `v4l2-ctl -d /dev/video0 --set-fmt-video=width=768,height=288,pixelformat=NV16 --stream-mmap=2 --stream-to=pic.yuv --stream-count=100`, it will drop frames. But if I set `--stream-mmap=3`, no frames will be droped.

Here is the output of  `gst-device-monitor-1.0`, which is about my FPGA camera.

```
Device found:

    name  : rkcif
    class : Video/Source
    caps  : video/x-raw, format=(string)NV12, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)NV16, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)YUY2, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)UYVY, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)NV21, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)NV61, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)RGB16, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-bayer, format=(string)bggr, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-bayer, format=(string)gbrg, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-bayer, format=(string)grbg, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-bayer, format=(string)rggb, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY8, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)I420, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)YV12, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)BGR, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)GRAY16_LE, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
            video/x-raw, format=(string)YVYU, width=(int)[ 64, 768, 8 ], height=(int)[ 64, 288, 8 ], framerate=(fraction)[ 1/1, 50/1 ];
    properties:
        device.path = /dev/video0
        udev-probed = false
        device.api = v4l2
        v4l2.device.driver = rkcif
        v4l2.device.card = rkcif
        v4l2.device.bus_info = platform:rkcif_dvp
        v4l2.device.version = 267214 (0x000413ce)
        v4l2.device.capabilities = 2233466881 (0x85200001)
        v4l2.device.device_caps = 85983233 (0x05200001)
    gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! ...
```

Comment: are you sure your camera supports 50 frames per second for a raw stream? that's very unusual. Can you post the output from `gst-device-monitor-1.0 Video`?

Comment: @Christian Fritz, Hello. What I connected is not a camera module, but an FPGA. The FPGA gives the data of YUYV, which is obtained by configuring the dummy camera according to the BT601 method.

Comment: thanks; did you already try forcing the io-mode to mmap using `v4l2src io-mode=2`?

Comment: @Christian Fritz，Thanks to your reply, I have tried which has no effect.

Comment: maybe try `blocksize=8192`? (or even `16384`)